# Read a text format data file into matrix even there is no space between values

Tags: r, data-analysis

I've attached an image to illustrate my question.

I have a text file containing a matrix, but the values don't have spaces between each other. There are 102 rows and 120 columns. Basically I want every number a separated cell inside a matrix after i import the data into R.

How to read such a file? read.table seems only be able to get one variable and recognise every row a extremely big number as a whole.

[image: data with no spaces between values]

Comment: What are the field widths?

Comment: Is each number a single digit long? If you don't have delimiters, you can use `read.fwf` to read a fixed-width data file.

Comment: Yes. I find read.fwf a feasible solution. Also I can use read.table to import, set the only variable to be class "character", then use apply(My_Data_Frame , strsplit, "") to generate a list where every value is a single digit long.